# Defining a style via script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I have an HTML code where I want to define the style using a dynamic variable. Basically I want to change the color of a button based on the URL the user came from.

change the color of the ID="wtv" using jscript

Something like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("link1").style.color = "blue";
</script>
```

link1 is the ID of the < a > tag

The style item is as follows:

```
.megamenu-nav li a link1{
     color:#EAAB00
}
```

I want to define the color within a script with a dynamic variable.

Comment: Are you trying to do this through CSS or Javascript?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried:<script>
document.getElementById(".megamenu-nav li a").style.color = btn_color;
</script>

Comment: And does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit off but you could change the style directly using js.
Example below uses a button but you could easily implement it when the page loads.

```
<script>

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var url = document.referrer; // Grabs the previous URL
  var hex = getHexCode(url); // Function where you decide what hex value you want to use.
  document.getElementById('p2').style["background-color"] = hex; // change style of the element.
})

function getHexCode(url) {
 var hex;
 if (url.length > 30) {
   hex = '#3333ff';
 } else {
   hex = '#ff0000';
 }
 return hex;
}

</script>
```

Here it is implemented in JSFiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/7x7u79tr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JQuery code to change the `button` color:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var buttonColor = '#EAAB00';
  $("#link1").css({
    'color': buttonColor
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='link1'>Some link</button>
```